# Compressibility factor hydrogen

Tags: openmodelica, hydrogen

I'm newbie in modelica and I'm trying to simulate a pressurization of a tank with high pressure hydrogen gas by opening a valve. The idea is to verify the change in flow through the valve with the decrease in pressure over time in the reservoir.

I verified that the model is not considering the compressibility factor. What is the easiest way to implement this factor?